# Javascript / S3 multiple file upload

Tags: javascript, upload, amazon-s3

I'm looking for a way to select and upload multiple files to Amazon S3, something in the vein of Uploadify, but with the following constraints :

1. No flash or HTML 5 - but AJAX and iframe tricks are allowed.
2. Multiple selection must happen in a single dialog.
3. Files must be sent directly to Amazon (there is no intermediary server to handle them).

Also, Amazon S3 does not allow uploading multiple files in a single request, so this means every file will have to be sent with a distinct request to a distinct URL, so I need to specify what those URLs will be.

Are any components around that might do this, or any known techniques I could leverage to build my own? Thank you.

Comment: Ended up accepting the Flash dependency and going for SWFUpload for multiple uploads (along with its own slew of problems).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain HTML file uploads are limited to one file at a time.

Javascript is restricted from accessing the user's file system, and must depend on the HTML file upload mechanism.

Consequently, we are left only with the complex options such as Flash, Java applets, or browser plugins. If they are not acceptable, you will not be able to support multiple file uploads.